# Isomorphic linear operator spaces and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $E$ and $F$ be vector spaces. Denote the space of all linear operators on $E$ to be $\operatorname{Hom}(E,E).$ Let $\Psi:\operatorname{Hom}(E,E)\to \operatorname{Hom}(F,F)$ be an isomorphism. Let $f\in\operatorname{Hom}(E,E)$ and $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $f$. I am wondering whether $\lambda$ is still an eigenvalue of $\Psi(f)$.

Say $\psi:E\to F$ is an isomorphism. Then it induces an isomorphism $\Psi:\operatorname{Hom}(E,E)\to \operatorname{Hom}(F,F)$ defined by $f\mapsto \psi\circ f \circ \psi^{-1}.$ Say $x\in E$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$, where $fx=\lambda x.$ Then $\Psi(f)\psi(x)= \psi\circ f \circ \psi^{-1} (\psi(x))=\psi(f(x))=\lambda \psi(x).$ In this case $\lambda$ is still an eigenvalue of $\Psi(f).$ However, I am not sure if all isomorphisms $\Psi:\operatorname{Hom}(E,E)\to \operatorname{Hom}(F,F)$ are given in this way.

If there exists an isomorphism $\Psi:\operatorname{Hom}(E,E)\to \operatorname{Hom}(F,F)$ and $f\in \operatorname{Hom}(E,E)$ such that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $f$ but not of $\Psi(f)$, does it mean that eigenvalue of an operator is not preserved by isomorphism?

Comment: Is $\Psi$ a group isomorphism, a ring isomorphism, a vector space isomorphism?

Comment: It is a vector space isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

A vector space isomorphism $\Psi: \operatorname{Hom}(E) \to \operatorname{Hom}(F)$ will not necessarily preserve eigenvectors.  For instance, take $E = F = \Bbb R^2$, so that $\operatorname{Hom}(E)$ can be identified with the $2 \times 2$ matrices. Define $\Psi(A) = MA$, where $M = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right].$  Verify that if $A = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, then $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ but not an eigenvalue of $\Psi(A)$.

If $\Psi$ is an *algebra* or *ring* isomorphism (or even a unit-preserving algebra homomorphism), then eigenvalues are necessarily preserved.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me a hint on how to find such eigenvector of $\Psi(f)$ corresponding to a eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $f$ provided that $\Psi$ is a unit preserving algebra homomorphism?